# Assignment of structure in C

Tags: c, struct

Following function of **convolution**, *args* pointer of the relevant struct is passed and then I need to assign it to another struct of same kind. Is it correct to assign as given below or is it required to initialize the memory for **actual args**.

```
typedef struct
{
    int batchSize;
    int filters;
    int chan;
    int inSize;
    int kSize;
    int stride;
    float *padded_inp;
    float *kernal;
    float *conv_out;
    int convPad;
    int b; // IMAGE NUMBER
} compute_convFWD;

void *convolution(void *args)
{
    compute_convFWD *actual_args = args; // is this a correct assignment ?
    ...
}
```

Comment: What's your goal? Do you want to copy the struct?

Comment: `actual_args` becomes the same *value* as the `void*` pointer passed. It points to the *same* object. If you try initialising the memory you will destroy the data.

Comment: Do you just want a convenient pointer to the caller’s structure? Do you need your own copy of the structure? Does the copy have to persist after `convolution` returns or is it just temporary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To copy the struct, you should do (either)

```
compute_convFWD *convolute(const void *args) {
    compute_convFWD *conv = malloc(sizeof *conv);
    if (!conv) return NULL; // Check malloc
    memcpy(conv, args, sizeof *conv);
    return conv;
}
```

Or:

```
void convolute(compute_convFWD *conv, const void *args) {
    memcpy(conv, args, sizeof *conv);
}
```

And a cherry on top, some would call this... well, say less than pretty.

```
compute_convFWD convolute(const void *args) {
    compute_convFWD conv = *(const compute_convFWD *)args;
    return conv;
}
```

EDIT: Of course, other possibilities exist as well, but these are the most straightforward ones.

Answer (score 0):

`void*` pointers are automatically converted to every other pointer type (except function pointers), you only have to initialize the memory, if the caller didn't do it.

Comment: So it is needed to assign memory as follows before assigining the void pointer. ```compute_convFWD *actual_args = malloc(sizeof(*actual_args));```

Comment: No, as the caller should already allocated the required memory.

Answer (score 0):

> args pointer of the relevant struct is passed and then I need to
> assign it to another struct of same kind. Is it correct to assign as
> given below or is it required to initialize the memory for actual
> args.
>
> ```
>     compute_convFWD *actual_args = args; // is this a correct assignment ?
>     ... }
> ```

Yes it is correct. but your question is some how unclear.

if you are passing `void*`, and you are intend to operate on this pointer, then no need to allocate via `malloc()` any buffer, just cast or assign the `void*` like you did and do your function work on `actual_args` pointer.

if you dont want to change the original `void*` pointer, then you function signature should be changed to:

```
void *convolution(const void *args)
```

And then you need to allocate memory for the copy of `*args`, (this could be on the stack of function  `convolution` or on the `heap`. it depends on the size of the struct and your function demands. (you can copy part of `*args` again it depends on your `convolution` logic!).

for allocating on the stack of function `convolution`:

```
compute_convFWD actual_args = *((compute_convFWD*)args); // this initializing can be done with memset also
```

for allocating on the heap:

```
compute_convFWD* p_actual_args = (compute_convFWD*)malloc(sizeof(*(compute_convFWD*)args));

*p_actual_args = *((compute_convFWD*)args); // this initializing can be done with memset also
```

Again if you are working on few data members of the original struct, you can allocate just for the data members size that you are manipulating (no need to copy all the struct members in this case)